# Trouble with Russian pc's on my wifi

Tags: wifi

I've created a WiFi hotspot for the local community.

The problem is, some Russian PCs (Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7) can't get an internet connection (We have a lot of bypassing Russian fishing vessels and cargo ships).  The PCs obtain a valid IP address, and some of them can even manage to send some few packets - But none of them are usable on the network. They all say `Ограниченный доступ в Интернет` (`Limited internet access`).

The thing these PCs have in common is that they all run a Russian installation of Windows. They can't ping the router (one PC got one response, *ONCE*), they can't access any sites and Windows never asks `Is this network public, home or work?`.

No one else has problems with the WiFi hotspot - Danish and English Windows, Linux and OS X all work like a charm.

Can it be, that there is a difference between the Danish and English Windows installations, compared to the Russian installation?

PS: The hotspot is a airMAX rocket M from Ubiquiti Networks, Inc. (www.ubnt.com)

Comment: Can you give us some things that do work and some things that don't work? Can they reach any web sites at all? Can they ping the router?

Comment: They can't ping the router (One PC got one response - ONCE), they can't access any sites and Windows newer asks "Is this network public, home or work?".

Comment: Do they get an ARP reply from the router? Check with `ARP -a`. (The first thing you should always do when troubleshooting a problem like this is figure out *exactly* how far the clients get and determine what is the *very* first thing that doesn't work.)

Comment: Well - I'm a programmer, not a network guy. Will do that as soon as I can access a russian PC. I'll be back later :)

Comment: If this would be Slashdot I'd be tempted to tell you all a stupid joke... but nah, I'll skip.

Answer (score 1):

The wifi hot spot may be broadcasting in wifi channel that is not approved in Russia (eg 14). Try setting wifi AP to fixed channel 6. (full table of allowed channels http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/access_point/channels/lwapp/reference/guide/1240_chp.html)

Other difference that may cause the issue - windows computer name can by in Cyrillic, if the software from the router somehow interacts with such credential information, it may be confused of non-latin characters.

Comment: Well. I use channel 11. That should be allowed in Russia.
But the Computer Names are in Cyrillic. I'll ask the ubnt support team about Cyrillic computer names